# iText - PdfAcroForm seems slow

Tags: pdf, itext, pdf-generation

I am trying to fill in values in a PDF and attach some images in an API call.
After downloading the file, to fetch the fields in the PDF, I perform this action.

```
PdfAcroForm form = PdfAcroForm.getAcroForm(pdfDocument, true);
```

I have logged the timings for this, it comes out to be around 300 ms. At times, over 500 ms.

I may have pdfDocument with append mode on. Will that affect?
Also, what factors will affect the time taken to fetch the acro form?
Is there any alternative - a better approach to my requirement?

PFA a [sample PDF](https://acrobat.adobe.com/link/track?uri=urn:aaid:scds:US:3d5185a1-f433-3773-9a8c-2893c9db9a97) that I'm trying to read.

Comment: Your link leads to "Sorry but this download link has expired."

Comment: didnt notice that the free tool had a limit :) updated the link, @mkl can u try now once please, it should be accessible

Comment: I just tested opening the form in append mode (using `new StampingProperties().useAppendMode()`) and it takes between 90ms and 110ms here on a laptop from 2020. This doesn't appear too long. Also I don't see any changes introduced by opening the form (which might have caused slowness).